# Plotting CV Indices for Multiclass in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Following this [guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html) from Sklearn, i have modified the code a bit to also show the classes in the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from sklearn.datasets import  make_classification

x_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=2)
cmap_data = plt.cm.Paired
cmap_cv = plt.cm.coolwarm


def plot_cv_indices(cv, x_input, y_output, axis, n_folds, lw=10):
    """Create a sample plot for indices of a cross-validation object."""

    # Generate the training/testing visualizations for each CV split
    ii = 0
    for ii, (tr, tt) in enumerate(cv.split(X=x_input, y=y_output)):
        # Fill in indices with the training/test groups
        indices = np.array([np.nan] * len(x_input))
        indices[tt] = 1
        indices[tr] = 0
        # Visualize the results
        axis.scatter(
            range(len(indices)),
            [ii + 0.5] * len(indices),
            c=indices,
            marker="_",
            lw=lw,
            cmap=cmap_cv,
            vmin=-0.2,
            vmax=1.2,
        )

    # Plot the data classes at the end
    axis.scatter(
        range(len(x_input)), [ii + 1.5] * len(x_input), c=y_output, marker="_", lw=lw
    )

    # Formatting
    yticklabels = list(range(n_folds)) + ["Class"]
    axis.set(
        yticks=np.arange(n_folds + 1) + 0.5,
        yticklabels=yticklabels,
        xlabel="Samples",
        ylabel="CV Iterations",
        ylim=[n_folds + 1.2, -0.2],
        xlim=[0, len(x_input)],
    )

    axis.set_title("{}".format(type(cv).__name__), fontsize=15)

    axis.legend(
        [Patch(color=cmap_cv(0.19)), Patch(color=cmap_cv(0.87)), Patch(color='darkslateblue'), Patch(color='yellow')],
        ["Training", "Validation", "Class 0", "Class 1"],
        loc=(0.9, 1.02),
    )
    return axis


n_splits = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_cv_indices(kfold, x_train, y_train, ax, n_splits)
plt.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

So, for a binary problem, we get a figure like this:

[image]

It is "easy" to change the colors in the following part:

```
axis.legend(
    [Patch(color=cmap_cv(0.19)), Patch(color=cmap_cv(0.87)), Patch(color='darkslateblue'), Patch(color='yellow')],
    ["Training", "Validation", "Class 0", "Class 1"],
    loc=(0.9, 1.02),
)
```

But if we have a multiclass problem:

```
x_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_informative=10, n_classes=10)
```

We get the following figure:

[image]

So, we have two problems here:

1 - Classes don't become clearly visible in the bottom bar;

2 - And even if they were, we would have to manually change the colors for each one of them in the `axis.legend()` part of the code.

Does anyone have a solution for this? To make a better visualization and to automatically get the colors from the Class Bar to match the ones in the legend?